# Reputation of the user increased without activity

Tags: support, reputation, user-accounts

I noticed a user profile who has joined today, has not got any upvote for questions nor has answered any question on physics.SE, how did his reputation surge to 101 within such a short period of time?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141648

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Users that have (or had at one time) more than 200 reputation on any site in the network are granted an [association bonus](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/why-register) of 100 reputation on every other site.